# .htaccess rewrites: how to serve content from different folders while preserving URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a site I'm developing on localhost that will be deployed to a live host. I'm using an Apache server and want to use .htaccess to perform content redirections and rewrites.

The problem I'm confronting is serving content from different folders than what's shown in the URL, and I'm hitting walls with the MOD rewrites. I'll provide the current .htaccess code first, and then describe the folder structure and the intended functioning following it.

Here's what I have so far that isn't working:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" LOCALHOST=https://localhost/example
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" LIVEHOST=https://example.com
<If "req('Host') = 'localhost'">
    ErrorDocument 400 https://localhost/example/error/
    ErrorDocument 403 https://localhost/example/error/
    ErrorDocument 404 https://localhost/example/error/
    ErrorDocument 500 https://localhost/example/error/
</If>
<If "req('Host') != 'localhost'">
    ErrorDocument 400 https://example.com/error/
    ErrorDocument 403 https://example.com/error/
    ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/error/
    ErrorDocument 500 https://example.com/error/
</If>
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

#Redirect to localhost HTTPS:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#Redirect to livehost HTTPS:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Strip initial www on localhost:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:LOCALHOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#Strip initial www on livehost:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:LIVEHOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Strip out autoversion in extension:
    RewriteRule ^((ftp|https?):\/\/)?(.*)\.((?=.*\d)[a-z\d]+)?\.(css|ico|jpe?g|m?js|json|png|gif|svg|xml|webp|webmanifest|mp4|webm|ogv)$ $1$3.$5 [L]

#Just testing on Localhost here:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^example/(.+[/]?)$ example/pages/$1 [L]


#LOCALHOST error page:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/pages/error/ [L]

#LIVEHOST error page:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/error/ [L]

#LOCALHOST:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=ABSOLUTE_ROOT:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example/]
#LIVEHOST:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=ABSOLUTE_ROOT:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/]

</IfModule>
```

On localhost, the site root is:

```
https://localhost/example
```

On livehost, the site root will be:

```
https://example.com
```

In my .htaccess file, I've defined:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" LOCALHOST=https://localhost/example
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" LIVEHOST=https://example.com
```

This allows rewrite conditions like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
```

and:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
```

...which I'll need to branch to accomodate the site when served on localhost vs. the live site.

The following description is relative to the localhost environment, but I'll need code that will work for the live site as well (which is why I've defined the constants).

I want to craft .htaccess rewrites such as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule example/(.*)$ example/pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

...but I'm hitting walls trying to make it work.

Here's the folder structure:

- example/

  - pages/

    - home/
    - error/
    - [various folders with or without subfolder structures]
  - [folders with publicly accessible assets, e.g., folders with names like `css`, `favicons`, `fonts`, `images`, `javascript`]
  - private -> [folder containing server files and folders that should not be publicly accessible]

So, if the client navigates to:

```
example/home
example/error
example/all-other-pages
```

...without or without trailing forward-slashes, then the content should be served from:

```
example/pages/home
example/pages/error
example/pages/all-other-pages
```

...without changing the URL.

Exception: If the client navigates to the site root:

```
example
```

...without or without a trailing forward-slash, then the content should be served from:

```
example/pages/home
```

...without changing the URL.

In general, any navigation to `example/*` that does not have a corresponding `example/pages/*` will serve content from:

```
example/pages/error
```

...without changing the URL. (Although this does raise a question about best practices, raised at the end.)

So, if the client navigates to `example/css`, and there's no `example/pages/css` folder, it will serve `example/pages/error`.

But if the client navigates to `example/css/site.css`, then, if that asset does exist, it will serve it.

Note: A navigation to `example/pages` itself will serve the `example/pages/error` content, provided there's no `example/pages/pages` folder on the server (in which case it would, in fact, serve the content on that page without changing the URL).

Internal navigation (within server code) to `/pages/` directories should not be blocked.

Public navigations to the `example/private` would be blocked by the same mechanism for the pages folder assets, e.g., `example/private/my-stuff` would look for `example/pages/private/my-stuff` and find nothing, and thus redirect.

**Best practices question**: when redirecting to the error page, when should the URL be changed to the error page URL, and when should it be left alone, although serving content from `example/pages/error`? The redirects should support whatever is best practice here.

Many thanks!

Comment: _"On localhost, the site root is: `https://localhost/example`"_ - IMHO you'd spare yourself a lot of trouble, if you avoided _that_ to begin with. Set up a proper VirtualHost in your local dev environment, with a fake domain like `example.local`, and then use that to develop & test your site locally.